# Swift Newbie HELP "[<UITableViewCell 0x7fd692f15cb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key posterView."

Tags: ios, swift

Swift newbie here, taking an iOS Development class for the first time. I'm tasked w/ making an app that consumes a Movielist API and returns things such as the Movie Poster, Title, and Description. I got to the step where I add the elements for a Movie Poster, Title + Synopsis and am now getting the error shown in the title. My code goes as follows:

```
//
//  MovieViewController.swift
//  KS-Flix
//
//  Created by Karan on 2/9/22.
//

import UIKit

class MovieViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    
    
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var movies = [[String:Any]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=a07e22bc18f5cb106bfe4cc1f83ad8ed")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
             // This will run when the network request returns
             if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
             } else if let data = data {
                    let dataDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                 
                 self.movies = dataDictionary["results"] as! [[String:Any]]
                 
                 self.tableView.reloadData()

                    // TODO: Get the array of movies
                    // TODO: Store the movies in a property to use elsewhere
                    // TODO: Reload your table view data

             }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movies.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell") as! MovieCell
        
        let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
        let title = movie["title"] as! String
        cell.titleLabel.text = title
        
        return cell
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

My code structure looks like this:

[image]

Happy to clarify and show what the other files are, apologies in advance for the vague nature of the question - i've been ripping my hair out over this problem and can't figure. out what's wrong :(

Comment: see the most upvoted answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/xcode-how-to-fix-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-valu

Comment: Tried it out but it doesn't look like any of my outlets are throwing a warning :/

Comment: The class of `UITableViewCell` in Storyboard hasn't been set your subclass `MovieCell`, it's still a `UITableViewCell`.